# Dynamic composite delegation in Python

Tags: python, delegates

Update: I have found an answer to my question:
*How can I do what I think of as 'dynamic composite delegation' without recursive calls being generated from `__getattr__`?*

At this point I am happy with the functionality. I only wish I could have found a solution that didn't require a decorator on `__getattr__`. Decorators are problematic for debugging, and to create a decorator that can only be applied to exactly one method (`__geattr__`) does not seem Pythonic.

Use dynamic delegation by adding `__getattr__` and a decorator to your class:

```
class Story():
    @delegate(delegate_to='chapter book', 
              only_delegate='title')
    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
                             (self.__class__.__name__,attr_name))
```

And it works like this:

```
class Other():
    """ Placeholder for Chapter and Book classes """

my_story = Story()
chp1 = Other()
my_story.chapter = chp1
bk = Other()  
my_story.book = bk

#delegation, with 'chapter' having precedence over 'book'
bk.title = "Title from book"
chp1.title = "Title from chapter"
assert my_story.title == "Title from chapter"
del chp1.title
assert my_story.title == "Title from book"

#local override
my_story.title = "Title from story"
assert my_story.title == "Title from story"
```

The code for `delegate()` is:

```
def delegate(delegate_to:str, only_delegate:str=''):

    #split into lists at decoration time so we don't have split each time
    #an attribute is delegated
    delegate_to = delegate_to.split()
    only_delegate = only_delegate.split()

    def ga_decorator(fn):
        #the decorator can only be applied to getattr, not Pythonic :-(
        if fn.__name__ != '__getattr__' and fn.__name__ != 'ga_decorated':
            raise AttributeError("Delegation can only apply to '__getattr__'")

        def ga_decorated(self, attr_name):

            #To enable delegation on any attribute, set only_delegate=''
            if not only_delegate or (attr_name in only_delegate):

                #delegate_to is a list of members of 'self' that reference 
                #the objects we will delegate to. 
                for m in delegate_to:
                    if m in dir(self):
                        member = getattr(self, m)
                        if attr_name in dir(member):
                            return getattr(member, attr_name)

            return fn(self, attr_name)
        return ga_decorated 
    return ga_decorator
```

The `only_delegate` list can include methods and delegation works the same way.

If you want to delegate one attribute to one set of objects and other attributes to a different set of objects, stack on more delegation statements:

```
class Story():
    @delegate(delegate_to='collection', 
              only_delegate='archivist')
    @delegate(delegate_to='chapter book', 
              only_delegate='title author')
    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
                             (self.__class__.__name__,attr_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid creating recursive `__getattr__` calls in `__getattr__` is to replace

```
hasattr(obj, attr_name)
```

with

```
attr_name in dir(obj)
```

In the decorator, this:

```
            for m in delegate_to.split():

                #why does this cause recursion?
                if hasattr(self, m):
                    member = getattr(self, m)
                    if hasattr(member, attr_name):
                        return getattr(member, attr_name)
```

Becomes

```
            for m in delegate_to.split():
                if m in dir(self):
                    member = getattr(self, m)
                    if attr_name in dir(member):
                        return getattr(member, attr_name)
```

Based on my testing, `dir()` doesn't appear to make calls to `getattr` even indirectly.